# Tricky If Exists SQL query needed to check overlapped values

Tags: sql, exists

I am having a table in SQL server  which stores  MINIMUM_AMOUNT, MAXIMUM_AMOUNT and CURRENCY_ID. Now I want to frame an SQL query which will check the new values to be inserted are already existing in the table. Ex: My table is having 2 records as follows

```
RANGE_ID   MINIMUM_AMOUNT     MAXIMUM_AMOUNT    CURRENCY_ID
------------------------------------------------------------
 1         3000                 9000                3
 2         12000                17000               3
```

Now when user inserts a new record, it should not be in between the values already available

ie : The user should not be able to enter these value pairs

```
  1 ) Min Amount : 4000  , Max Amount : 5000 ,Currency Id : 3
        because this range already lies in the first record (RANGE_ID 1)
  2)  Min Amount : 8000 , Max Amount : 10000,Currency d : 3
        because the minimum amount is already present in the range specified in first record (3000-9000)
  3)   Min Amount : 8000, Max Amount : 15000 , currency Id=3
       because the minimum amount is already present in one range and the maximum amount is also present in another range
  4)   Min Amount : 2500 , Max Amount : 11000 ,Currency Id=3
        because the this range overlaps with the data in first record
```

User should be able to enter the above range with different Currency ID's.

I am looking for a If Exists query to check this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        RANGE_ID INT,
        MINIMUM_AMOUNT FLOAT,
        MAXIMUM_AMOUNT FLOAT,
        CURRENCY_ID INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table (RANGE_ID,MINIMUM_AMOUNT,MAXIMUM_AMOUNT,CURRENCY_ID) SELECT 1,3000,9000,3
INSERT INTO @Table (RANGE_ID,MINIMUM_AMOUNT,MAXIMUM_AMOUNT,CURRENCY_ID) SELECT 2,12000,17000,3

DECLARE @NewMin FLOAT,
        @NewMax FLOAT,
        @CurrencyID INT

SELECT  @NewMin = 4000,
        @NewMax = 5000,
        @CurrencyID = 3

SELECT  *
FROM    @Table
WHERE   CURRENCY_ID = @CurrencyID
AND     NOT (MINIMUM_AMOUNT > @NewMax OR MAXIMUM_AMOUNT < @NewMin)
```

This is the reverse of checking

- Full overlap
- Partial Overlap
- Internal Overlap

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it:

```
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM MinMaxTable mmt
    WHERE (mmt.CURRENCY_ID = @currencyID) AND
          (@minAmount BETWEEN mmt.MINIMUM_AMOUNT AND mmt.MAXIMUM_AMOUNT) AND
          (@maxAmount BETWEEN mmt.MINIMUM_AMOUNT AND mmt.MAXIMUM_AMOUNT)
)
BEGIN
    /* New data is within an existing range. */
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    /* Partially or completely outside an existing range. */
END;
```

Use `IF NOT EXISTS` to invert the condition.

Comment: This does not handle the overlapping

Answer (score 0):

```
select 1 
from currency_ranges R
where R.CURRENCY_ID = :newCurrency
and (
(R.MINIMUM_AMOUNT <= :newMin and R.MAXIMUM_AMOUNT >= :newMin)
or (R.MINIMUM_AMOUNT <= :newMax and R.MAXIMUM_AMOUNT >= :newMax)
)
```

This can be used as an EXISTS statement to check for overlaps in the ranges